# PrintWrite keeps throwing a file not found exception even though the file referenced is in the project root directory

Tags: java

The file data.txt is in the root directory of my project and it keeps throwing exceptions. What might be the problem?

```
public static void Records(String record)  {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    pw.println(record + "\n");
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: There should not be any problem with this, can you take a look at your code once again, because this seems like a code that should work.

Comment: Seems to work, forgot to put a throw clause in the main method. Now it only writes the last record though. How could I get it to simply just add lines and not rewrite the whole file?

Comment: use `FileWriter ` @JakeTheSteak

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Try using append: pw.append(record + "\n");